# substitute built-in ColdFusion function between server versions

Tags: coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, cfml

I've got some functions that are built-in in CF10 and not in CF9.

I'd like to make the function available if it is not defined. I thought a simple `try-catch` would do the trick, but I'm still getting the "The names of user-defined functions cannot be the same as built-in ColdFusion functions." error

```
try {
    // override function if it doesn't exist
    function listRemoveDuplicates(inList,delim)
    {
        var listStruct = {};
        var i = 1;

        for(i=1;i<=listlen(inList, delim);i++)
        {
            listStruct[listgetat(inList,i)] = listgetat(inList,i);
        }

        return structkeylist(listStruct);
    }
}
catch(e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

Is there an `if` statement or any other way of dealing with this?

Comment: You might be better off putting all of these functions in a separate file and then checking the version you're running whether to include the file or not.

Comment: That said, have you had a look at [CFBackport](https://github.com/misterdai/cfbackport)?

Comment: The problem is that the file needs to *compile* before it can be run, and your code won't compile for the reason the error message cites. Obviously try/catch is a runtime thing, so doesn't help. @FishBelowtheIce has given you a good answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to put your functions in a separate file and then only include that file if the version number is the right number. Something like:

```
<cfif ListFirst(server.coldfusion.productVersion) LT 10>
  <cfinclude template="/udfs/CF10functions.cfm">
</cfif>
```

If that doesn't work for you, there's no reason you can't wrap all of your functions inside a single `if` block.

```
if (ListFirst(server.coldfusion.productVersion) LT 10) {

  function listRemoveDuplicates(inList,delim) {
    ...
  }

  function foo(arg) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I see, there's no way of having the function inside the same file

Comment: There might be. I was only suggesting how I'd probably do it.

Comment: You might also have a look at [IsFunction](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=286) from CFLib.org.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [GetFunctionList()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6cfe.html)

> **Description**
> Displays a list of the functions that are available in ColdFusion.
>
> **Returns**
> A structure of functions.

```
if (NOT structKeyExists(getFunctionList(),"listRemoveDuplicates")) {
    // override function if it doesn't exist
    function listRemoveDuplicates(inList,delim)
    {
        var listStruct = {};
        var i = 1;

        for(i=1;i<=listlen(inList, delim);i++)
        {
            listStruct[listgetat(inList,i)] = listgetat(inList,i);
        }

        return structkeylist(listStruct);
    }
}
```